# Symfony email validation (not using Form Framework)

Tags: php, validation, symfony1, symfony-1.4

As the title suggest, I'm looking for a way to validate emails (or other string formats) using the Symfony Framework (without having to use the Form Framework).

I've done some searching around, but every example given is using the Form classes...

And I know that I can use external classes or libraries, but I'm just curious if there is something that I could use from within Symfony that'll work.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
$email = "email@to.validate";

$validator = new sfEmailValidator(); // just using this as an example - I know it doesn't work :p

$validator->check($email); // returns true or false if it validates
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do something like the following -- you don't need to use the form framework to use the validator framework:

```
$email = 'email@to.validate';
$v = new sfValidatorEmail();

try {
    $email = $v->clean($email);
} catch (sfValidatorError $e) {
    // email invalid
}
```

Comment: Ah, yea I remember reading about that. I guess I was just trying to avoid the use of Exception handling for the email validation. So I guess that's the only way to do it via Symfony...

Comment: @xil3 Is the exception handling so problematic?! The other alternative is to get the regex used by `sfValidatorEmail` and do the checking yourslef with `preg_match`: `/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i`

Comment: It's not that problematic, but if I am doing a lot of different types of validation, would I be able to stick them all within the `Try` clause and be able to distinguish which ones error'd out from the `sfValidatorError` object returned?

Comment: To add on from my last commend - for example, if I was using `sfValidatorDate` and `sfValidatorEmail`. If those were both placed in the `try` clause, could they be distinguished, or do I need a `try` `catch` statement for each.

Comment: Actually, never mind - not sure what I was thinking. Of course I'd need one for each, because if it error'd out on the first one it would immediately go to the `catch` clause and skip the rest.

Comment: @xil3 Well, the exception has a `getValidator` method, which allows you to get the instance of the validator that failed. That may do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reconsider using sfValidatorEmail, it's not quite accurate. Use filter_var instead (you can make your own validator based on filter_var if you want).